How to detect if a Java application running as a systemd service is operating within an LXC container?
I am trying to detect if java app running as systemd service is operating inside lxc container from app itself through java code.
checking /proc/self/cgroup file for “lxc” string works if app is not started as a service.
If its started as a service this file does not contain anything related to “lxc”
I need a way to detect if java app is running inside lxc even if its started through sudo service serviceName start

Are you asking about how the Java app can determine of itself whether it is running inside an lxc container?  And either way, why is this important?

yes itself.
if its running inside container i change the way memory usage is calculated.
If running inside container memavailable = memory.limit_in_bytes - memory.usage_in_bytes
There is a function used to calculate available memory called Pointer.availablePhysicalBytes of bytedeco. This does not work correct on container env thats why i am trying to calculate it through cgroup files in container env.

Related discussion:
https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp/discussions/780

Ok.  Does the the version that does work in the container then not work outside?

Or: can you not tell the Java app which memory computation to use?  Via command-line argument or system property, for example?

I think i couldnt understand your first question. Pointer.availablePhysicalBytes does work for me if app is not running inside LXC. if its running inside LXC it doesnt work.
well, i dont pref to do such thing.
I mean i dont know where this software is installed and how, thats up to user. Also mostly its started as a service thats why i am looking for a reliable way to detect LXC, so that i can change the mem available calculation from Pointer.availablePhysicalBytes  to reading cgroup files. So i believe i cannot tell. It needs to detect if its running inside LXC and change calculation

As i mentioned in thread, detecting LXC through /proc/self/cgroup works if app is not started as a systemd service. If its started as systemd service that file doesnt contain lxc string. For docker this is easy, i can just check ./dockerenv file and decide if its dockerized or not in both systemd or normal start case.

The point of the first question was that it would be ideal to have a way to compute the available memory that produces the correct result whether you use it inside a container or outside, so that you don't need to make the determination in the first place.

As for telling the app what method to use for the memory computation, I think you're giving up too easily. You cannot reasonably expect to provide zero-configuration adaptation to every possible execution environment.  It's ok if people who set up a systemd service around your app (for example) need to configure or invoke it differently than they would do in a different context.  You don't necessarily have to know.  You just need to provide a way for your app to be told.

I agree. Using a single calculation which works in both lxc and standalone would be great. do you know a way to calculate mem available in lxc?
